# Map each element of a list in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, rdd, spark-graphx

I'm working with an RDD which pairs are structured this way: [Int, List[Int]] my goal is to map the items of the list of each pair with the key. So for example I'd need to do this:

```
RDD1:[Int, List[Int]]
<1><[2, 3]>
<2><[3, 5, 8]>

RDD2:[Int, Int]
<1><2>
<1><3>
<2><3>
<2><5>
<2><8>
```

well I can't understand what kind of transformation would be needed in order to get to RDD2. Transformations list can be found [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations). Any Idea? Is it a wrong approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flatMap`:

```
 val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, List(2, 3)), (2, List(3, 5, 8))))
 val rdd2 = rdd1.flatMap(x => x._2.map(y => (x._1, y)))

 // or:
 val rdd2 = rdd1.flatMap{case (key, list) => list.map(nr => (key, nr))}

 // print result:
 rdd2.collect().foreach(println)
```

Gives result:

```
(1,2)
(1,3)
(2,3)
(2,5)
(2,8)
```

`flatMap` created few output objects from one input object.

In your case, inner map in flatMap maps tuple (Int, List[Int]) to List[(Int, Int)] - key is the same as input tuple, but for each element in input list it creates one output tuple. `flatMap` causes that each element of this List becomes one row in RDD

Comment: Thank you, I stupidly thought doing a map inside a map (or flatMap) was something wrong. I'm a beginner. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Matt Inner map is not Spark's transformation - it's standard Scala List operation :) So you can use it inside flatMap. You can't use only other Spark actions and transformations, i.e. map on RDD, DataFrame or Dataset